# Mac adding login items from Terminal

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to add the Unix executable 'main' run on start up using the login items on Mac. I tried using this

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
defaults write loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{ 'Path' = 'main' = 0; }'
```

But I get this error:

```
2020-11-04 14:57:46.738 defaults[4306:125061] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 1. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2020-11-04 14:57:46.793 defaults[4306:125061] Could not parse: { Path = main = 0; }.  Try single-quoting it.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the immediate cause of your problem is that you are using single quotes for everything.  Try something like:

```
defaults write loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{ "Path" = "main"; "Hide" = "0"; }'
```

However, I doubt that this mechanism for setting login items still works.  If I say

```
defaults read loginwindow
```

I don't see any `AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary`, yet I definitely have some login items defined.

Comment: I had tried using doubles quotes and I got an error saying to try using single quotes. Do you think you know any other way of doing this if it is now outdated?

Comment: @TanujKS Note that I used both single and double quotes, in such a way that the nesting is clear.  For newer ways to do it, see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html).